# Few Microsoft DevOps questions

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, devops

I'm new with DevOps and wonder if someone can clarify a few things:

1. It's the new name for Team Foundation server as I understand. If so could I install it on a local server and have all projects stored locally and not the cloud?
2. I believe it's free for 5 developers and no fees?
3. I'll like to use this version instead of other repositories, does it support migrating from other repositories out of the box? I haven't seen any documentation but in case anyone knows for sure.
4. I don't use Azure, would this cause any issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. yes
2. [no](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/pricing/details/devops/server/)
3. yes, it can [git clone a repo](https://www.jpaul.me/2018/10/importing-a-github-repo-to-azure-devops-repo/)
4. no

Comment: So regarding number 2, I thought it's free for upto 5 developers for internal use? We will not use any features for the cloud

Comment: that would be correct for Azure Devops Services, not for Azure Devops Server

Comment: Just to make sure there's no misinterpretation, all I want to do is have a repository to check in/out code for internal use. We don't need any cloud services or store anything in the cloud. Any reporting tools would be handy but not necessary. So based on that if I download and install DevOps on my local server for 5 developers is free to use but should I need to use any cloud features then it's chargeable? Thx

Comment: you can just use github? cloud azure devops (free for 5 users, like you mentioned)

Comment: Sorry not sure what GitHub had to do with this? If I can use DevOps in the above manner for free that would answer my question but interested to know about GitHub

Comment: both github and azure devops (as a service, not devops server) are free to use as repos, but I believe Azure Devops Server is never free

Answer (score 1):

Azure DevOps Server is heavy-duty enterprise-grade software, which includes the need for [licensing](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/devops/server/). Azure DevOps Server Express is free for 5 users, however.

If you have a small team and limited bandwidth to take on the responsibility of maintaining (database backups, security patches, major/minor version upgrades, etc) this type of software, **use a cloud service**. You'll thank me later.

For what you're describing, private GitHub repos are probably more than adequate. Azure DevOps (cloud-hosted, not on-prem) would also fit the bill and *is* free for 5 users.

As for point #3, it entirely depends on what "other repositories" means to you. Are you talking about other repository *technologies*, like SVN? If so, you'll have to convert it. If you're talking about other Git repos, then all you have to do is set a new remote and push it.

Comment: We have an external team that would maintain the updates, service packs etc. What we can't have is the code being placed onto the cloud. As long as it's free to use for 5 developers then we're good to use it. I'm probably confused with the different names/services so I'll dig into the link provided. As for other repos, yes SVN

Comment: Why can't you use cloud-based services? Is there a regulatory/legal reason or is it simply an inscrutable management decree? Also, you'd have to use Azure DevOps Server Express, as that's the one that is licensed to be free for 5 users. You will also have to migrate your SVN repository to either TFVC or Git, with Git being the preference.

Comment: Yes management decision. Unfortunately there is no way around this. I'll read up on server express and Git as I'm not familiar with Git(unless it's GitHub). Thanks

Comment: "GitHub" is a Git repository hosting platform, so you can't really be familiar with GitHub without being familiar with Git. Git is Git. It's the same technology across all of the platforms that can host repositories.